On the very chapter matthew 23:23
Why was Jesus silent about the don't and do?
He did mention to any people around him that don't give the tithe!
Neither did He make a parable as He has done in all His conclusions.
To me I believe that we don't have an immediate conclusion of saying we shouldn't because it is silent.
And none of the apostles came with a conclusive remark in their letters that a tithe is not for the NT dispensation.
Our philosophical and Theological research may be good but I believe they don't make a conclusive remark on what the scriptures are silent about.
Hebrews 3:16 tells that all scriptures were spirit led.
Yes it's well said about Habakkuk according to your research (I respect it)
My question is why would we conclude it as a no if the apostles didn't say no, neither did christ?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  Here, we examine the text of the Bible but make no comment about personal morality.

"My question is [almost incomprehensible]".  (Even the given Title isn't a question.) Please explicitly quote the verse you are asking about, and then ask a simple question about what the author could have meant.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The "tithe" was part of the Old Covenant. It's purpose, in a nutshell, was to provide the Levites with an inheritance (Num. 18:20-24). The other tribes got land. The Levites, who minister to God on their behalf, got a ten percent tithe from everyone else (Lev. 27:32).

And the Lord spake unto Aaron, Thou shalt have no inheritance in their
land, neither shalt thou have any part among them: I am thy part and
thine inheritance among the children of Israel. And, behold, I have
given the children of Levi all the tenth in Israel for an inheritance,
for their service which they serve, even the service of the tabernacle
of the congregation. Neither must the children of Israel henceforth
come nigh the tabernacle of the congregation, lest they bear sin, and
die. But the Levites shall do the service of the tabernacle of the
congregation, and they shall bear their iniquity: it shall be a
statute for ever throughout your generations, that among the children
of Israel they have no inheritance. But the tithes of the children of
Israel, which they offer as an heave offering unto the Lord, I have
given to the Levites to inherit: therefore I have said unto them,
Among the children of Israel they shall have no inheritance. (Num.
18:20-24)

In the New Covenant, which replaced the Old Covenant (Heb. 10:9), Christians are not obligated to pay a ten percent tithe to the House of Levi. Nor does the New Covenant specify a fixed tithe to any other member of the clergy, or to any church facility.
What the New Testament does say is that it is good to give a gift. Paul encourages it. But he is clear that he is asking, not commanding.

Praying us with much intreaty that we would receive the gift, and take
upon us the fellowship of the ministering to the saints. And this they
did, not as we hoped, but first gave their own selves to the Lord, and
unto us by the will of God. Insomuch that we desired Titus, that as he
had begun, so he would also finish in you the same grace also.
Therefore, as ye abound in every thing, in faith, and utterance, and
knowledge, and in all diligence, and in your love to us, see that ye
abound in this grace also. I speak not by commandment, but by occasion
of the forwardness of others, and to prove the sincerity of your love.
(2 Cor. 8:4-8)

We should give as our heart determines, whether sparingly or bountifully, and with cheerfulness, not out of necessity.

But this I say, He which soweth sparingly shall reap also sparingly;
and he which soweth bountifully shall reap also bountifully. Every man
according as he purposeth in his heart, so let him give; not
grudgingly, or of necessity: for God loveth a cheerful giver.(2 Cor.
9:6-7)

Morally speaking, tithing is still a good thing. The church building lease or mortgage costs money. The utilities cost money. The sound system costs money. The donuts and coffee cost money. The staff that keeps the place running costs money. When we go to church, we are taking advantage of a great of expense for free. The pastor works all week preparing a sermon, and the laborer is worthy of his wages. So, we should tithe if we participate in a church facility. They do a great deal of work at great expense to provide us with our weekly experience.
BUT, be wary of places with pastors who make six figures on the backs of congregants who can't pay their rent or utilities. Paul himself, an apostle, who has done more for Christianity than just about anyone but Jesus himself, says to Timothy that, "having food and raiment let us be therewith content (1 Tim. 6:8)." No pastor should be living in the lap of luxury while faithful people in his congregation are going without.
